# Running .EXE file made in visual studio 2005 failure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I would like to run a .exe file made with visual studio 2003 but I get an error every time I run it on a windows 7 machine, vista machine, and xp machine. The error on Windows 7 and vista says `"application has stopped working"` and then makes me close the error box.

In windows xp it's a little different error, `"the application failed to operate (0xc0000135) Click on OK to terminate the application."`

Comment: Made in visual studio 2005 or 2003 ? Title/body mismatch

Answer (score 2):

That error code seems to indicate the application failed to initialize correctly.

It is possible that the anticipated .NET version is not present.

Comment: I just looked at all the machines I tested on and I have v4 through v1.0 on all machines

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, VS 2003 by default compiles against the .NET 1.1 library. There is no straightforward way of installing this on a Windows 7 or Vista box. Do you need to compile it against the .NET 1.1 library, or can you load it in VS2005, change the output .net version to 2.0 or higher, and recompile the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code to the application, try running the application in debug mode and stepping through line by line until you find the exception. If you do not have the source code, possibly try running the application in a couple different compatibility modes. Another option to try is to check the windows event log for anything more specific.

If you want to get really deep into it, you can use SysInternals ProcMon.exe and filter on the failing exe to view the WinAPI calls that are happening during the failure.

Also, a basic search of forums shows that error is usually accompanied with framework issues. Either recompile the application or check out what your required framework is in the VS2003 project settings.